# How can I use the old iostream.h in C++ (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 Project and converted it successfully with MS VS Professional 2010 Trial. No conversion problems occured. However, when building the converted project it tells me, that "iostream.h" cannot be found.

I am aware of the new and standardized "iostream" and the "using namespace std" fix.

But I need to use the old iostream.h. Is there a way to accomplish that? The reason is, that this project relies on an old static lib using the old iostream.h.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would need the old iostreams.

Comment: Visual Studio breaks binary compatibility with every release, intentionally.  You *can't* use a static lib compiled with Visual C++ 6 with a Visual Studio 10 project.

Comment: That means, if I don't have a copy of Visual C++ 6.0, I'm screwed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have source code relying on iostream.h, change it.
If you have source code that you absolutely cannot change, write iostream.h yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

A static library cannot possibly rely on a header file. A header file is included by source code or other header files, the static library consists of object code. The library's header files can depend on iostream.h, though.
The library itself can depend on the C++ standard library.
I assume that there have been incompatible changes to Microsoft's standard library since MSVC 6.0, so if you do not have source code or a newer version of your static library, then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Note that your code does **not** implement `<iostream.h>`, although it may be close enough for some uses.  The standard `<iostream>` differs from the classical `<iostream.h>` in a number of places, all of which will require (usually simple) rework in the source code.

Comment: Yeah, there is one header file of the static library, which depends on iostream.h. But doesn't it mean, the library depends on it? I thought without the library's header files, the library cannot be used? But I'm quite new to the topics linker, header files, libraries, etc. Unfortunately I don't have the code of that library. So I guess there's nothing I can do if I want to use Vistual Studio 2010?

Comment: I was able to write a library Wrapper and put it all into a DLL (using MS Visual C++ 6.0). That DLL can be used in Visual Studio 2010! It seams like all dependent code parts were packed into the DLL, which is great for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using precompiled headers? If so, then you'll have to include `iostream.h` within the `stdafx.h`file or remove the precompiled headers. Anyway, there seems no reason using the deprecated `iostream.h` instead of `iostream`, so maybe you should change the parts of the code that need the old version (if so).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

with

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
```